# Sbt-concat support multiple bundle?

Tags: playframework-2.3, sbt-web, sbt-concat

I am using sbt-concat to create bundles for JS in my application.  However, it does not seem to support creating multiple bundles.

In my application, I would like to create a base level js for global use.  Then I also want to create a components bundle which will be used on certain pages.

Is this something sbt-concat can do?

Answer (score 2):

No it does not, but you should pretty easily be able to change it into something that does, or just create your own plugin that does.

This is actually the entire codebase that is the sbt-concat plugin (64 lines including whitespace and comments):
https://github.com/mariussoutier/sbt-concat/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mariussoutier/sbt/ConcatPlugin.scala

Comment: I really would love to try.  However, I am also very disappointed by part of the community.  Everything seems to be obvious to a small group of people.  This is not going to help the community to grow.  The tool needs to be easy to use.  The goal of Play framework is to improve developer's productivity.  However, using the framework requires developers to spend more time to learn something else.  I don't believe this is the original intention.  Really hope the tool can be easier to use.  Honestly, I don't know how and I am still trying to figure how to use the plugin itself.